# Create a 'universal' reusable View?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, javascript

Is it possible to create a View that essentially a skeleton, and can be reused over and over again (on different parts of the site) simply using different input i.e. something like different node ID's?

I want to be able to create a new Views Slideshow Gallery (The gallery is a jQuery slider) just by adding content to my custom content type, Photos. The way I have it set up now, I have to create a new Photos content type, keep it not published, and then plug that Node ID to a brand new View using the Views Slideshow formatting. As you can imagine this is quite a laborious task.

This question has applications outside my specific uses. The core question is, can you create a (dynamic?) view that will automatically take different inputs for use in a content type?

Answer (score 3):

What you may be looking for is "Contextual Filters"

Here's a good tutorial I have that explains how to implement them:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJFMTDuaxy8

There's also a way to call a View directly from a template, which can be pretty useful in some cases:

```
views_embed_view("slideshow_gallery", "page", array() );
```

Comment: LOL the same answer as mine just 3 mins before ;P

Answer (score 1):

[Contextual filters](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views) is what youre looking for.

You can declare them when rendering a view programmatically ([views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)?).

However, obviously this depends by how deep and specific are your needs